# Python: Non-abstract methods in an Abstract Base Class

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, self-reference, abc

I'm implementing a meta class as follows:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Algorithm(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    # lots of @abstractmethods

    # Non-abstract method
    @property
    def name(self):
        ''' Name of the algorithm '''
        return self.__class__.__name__

class MyLittleAlgorithm(Algorithm):        
    def magic(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, I'm under the impression that the following two prints ought to give the same result.

```
a = MyLittleAlgorithm()
print(a.magic)
print(a.name)
```

but in fact I get:

```
>>> print(a.magic)
<bound method MyLittleAlgorithm.magic of <__main__.MyLittleAlgorithm object at 0x11242f438>>
>>> print(a.name)
MyLittleAlgorithm
```

The behaviour I'm after is the latter one. (I want every algorithm which inherits from `Algorithm` to have a `.name` @property which it can use to refer to itself.)

Please note that I do not want to [instantiate the meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757299/python-testing-an-abstract-base-class). I merely want the instances of the children of it to have the `.name` @property without me having to write out the code for each one explicitly.

Comment: Is that because `name` is a property and `magic` is a method?

Comment: @quamrana,  Yup. That's right <facepalm>. It's always the simple things that get you...

Comment: My apologies for a potentially obsolete question. I'll let admins decide what to do with it, but I'm happy for it to be deleted.