# Unit Testing Abstract Base and Child Classes

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

Unit testing newbie here. I have an abstract base class with one concrete, public method and one abstract, private method. Several child classes implement this private method:

```
@add_metaclass(ABCMeta)
class Base(object):

    def concrete(self, x, y):
        x = self._abstract(x)
        return x, y

    @abstractmethod
    def _abstract(self, x):
        pass


class Child(Base):

    def _abstract(self, x):
        return x + 1
```

What is the best way to unit test the methods in these classes? In my initial attempt I created a `MockBase` and a set of tests in `BaseTests` common to all children of the original base class (`BaseTests` skips tests to avoid redundancy on execution). Child tests inherit from `BaseTests`.

```
class MockBase(Base):

    def _abstract(self, x):
        return x


class BaseTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        if cls is BaseTests:
            raise unittest.SkipTest("Skipping BaseTests.")
        super(BaseTests, cls).setUpClass()

    def setUp(self):
        super(BaseTests, self).setUp()
        self.class_ = MockBase()

    def test_concrete_returns_y(self):
        _, y = self.class_.concrete(1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(y, 1)


class TestChild(BaseTests):

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestChild, self).setUp()
        self.class_ = Child()

    def test_concrete_returns_x_plus_1(self):
        x, _ = self.class_.concrete(1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(x, 2)
```

This approach seems to work, but I'm wondering if it's the most elegant and scalable option.

Comment: this has already been answered here i believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757299/python-testing-an-abstract-base-class
The tl;dr is that you can use `unittests.mock.patch` to clear all abstract methods from the base class in order to instantiate it.